# Laravel 5.2 Class not found but class is there with namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**UPDATE 01/26/16 10:30pm EST:** Through a lot of Google searching I discovered that I was misunderstanding how to utilize namespaces and custom classes.  If anyone else is having this issue read this tutorial: http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-class-in-laravel-5/
It's short and very easy to understand.  It helped resolve this issue and move me along to my next error... :D

**ISSUE:**
Attempting to freshly install Laravel 5 and convert my Laravel 4 code to Laravel 5.

**REQUEST:** Please help me find the error and provide detailed instructions on how to correct it.

**ERROR:**
FatalErrorException in additionalPCs.php line 4:
Class 'App\Library\AdditionalPCs\additionalComputer' not found

**Notes:** I have put the additionalComputer.php file in both its own directory App\Libary\additionalPCs and directly into the App\Libary directory.  Both places produce the same error.  I am using namespaces. (possibly incorrectly)

**Composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Library\additionalPCs;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    Protected $layout = 'master';
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        /** Wayne - 03-02-2014 - Moved for loop to a method within its own class. */
        $numberofpcs = new additionalPCs();
        $addtpcs=$numberofpcs->display();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('index')->with('addtpcs', $addtpcs)->with('businesstypelist', businesstype::dropdown())->with('contracttermlist',ContractTerm::dropdown());
    }
}
```

**additionalPCs.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Library;

class additionalPCs extends additionalComputer {
    public function display() {
        return $this->displayMenu();    
    }
}
```

**additionalComputer.php** (I have also attempted  use App\Library\additionalComputer;)

```
<?php
namespace App\Library;

use App\Library\AdditionalPCs\additionalComputer;

class additionalPCs extends additionalComputer {
    public function display() {
        return $this->displayMenu();    
    }
}
```

Comment: The link you gave is broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update after your post update**:

You want to use additionalComputer, so you have to import his namespace, like so:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Library;

    use App\Library\additionalComputer;

    class additionalPCs extends additionalComputer {
        public function display() {
            return $this->displayMenu();    
        }
    }
```

(Added namespace import for additionalComputer)

**Original post:**

You have this line in your library:

```
namespace App\Library\AdditionalPCs;
```

To use AdditionalPCs (in for example your controller), change:

```
use App\Library\AdditionalPCs;
```

To

```
use App\Library\AdditionalPCs\AdditionalPCs;
```

> The first `AdditionalPCs` is from your namespace, the second is your class name. Your class AdditionalPCs is in the sub namespace AdditionalPCs.

**Important**: it's `new AdditionalPCs()` (see the beginning `A` instead of `a`), it must be your class name **exactly**! That's a general rule!

Be care with your names (case sensitivity). It's better to use the code conventions from PSR-2: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: This is not quite working.  I did change a couple of items but then it brings me to another error.

I changed the use to use App\Library\additionalPCs; and removed the directory additionalPCs so now the additionalPCs.php file is located in the app\Library directory.  

I received my next error: Class 'App\Library\AdditionalPCs\additionalComputer' not found.  Okay, so I moved my additionalComputer.php file into the app\library folder and even tried to create an AdditionalPCs directory and put in there to no avail.  the error still remains.  Not sure why it looks for the AdditonalPCs folder.

Comment: I added the code for the additionalComputer.php to the original post.

Comment: My correction is correct. I don't know, but did you update all the code? I still see the wrong namespace included. ;-)

And right, `App\Library\AdditionalPCs\additionalComputer` doesn't exist. additionalComputer is in the namespace App\Library, so it's `App\Library\additionalComputer`.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is user error and not your suggestion.  There is no doubt in my mind about that. :D  I just ran into the same problem on a different class and it is not working.  I am brand new with namespaces.  I have read about them but this is my first attempt at using them.  Sorry, I didn't update the code on stackoverflow  I only added the additional code for addtionalComputer.php.  I will update the rest of it.

Comment: I have updated the error and the code for what I am using in the original post.  I want to say **Thank you very much** for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: I thought that as well and have already attempted that.  It didn't work.  The error still persists.  I have updated the code in the original post to reflect the use of use App\Library\additionalComputer.  I have even tried to add it to AdditionalPCs.  It keeps looking towards a directory called AdditionalPCs even though one doesn't exist.  I am not sure where it is getting the directory from. Class 'App\Library\AdditionalPCs\additionalComputer' not found

Comment: Hey, I think I discovered why it is looking for a directory called AdditionalPCs.  I did an agent ransack search for additionalPCs and I found the autoload_classmap.php file contains **'App\\Library\\additionalComputer' => $baseDir . '/app/Library/AdditionalPCs/additionalComputer.php',**.  I tried to run composer dump-autoload & php artisan clear-compiled but that didn't work.  I don't know if I can delete the autoload_classmap.php or where it is getting the information from.  The only places I have additionalPCs that relate to the class are in the IndexController.php & addtionalPCs.php file.

Comment: I think we did it.  I went back through the code again and found that I changed something in addition to what was listed.  I originally had namespace App\Library\AdditionalPCs; and while troubleshooting this I changed this to namespace App\Library\.  Well, I somehow managed to change it back to the original.  As soon as I removed the AdditionalPCs and went back to App\Library I got to my next error **Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found**.  This means that it must be finding the class and I can move on to troubleshooting this error.  - Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 5):

Namespace of each class is the container directory of the that class not the class file itself.

In your additionalPCs.php file for the namespace, get rid of \AdditionalPCs, it should just be:

```
namespace App\Library;
```

Comment: If I could mark two of them as correct I would mark this as correct as well.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @scrfix If it was helpful to you, upvote it. It is a responsibility not a privilege to upvote helpful literature